# How do I center a footer in IE 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Why isn't the footer centered in IE8 on [this site](http://www.isysla.com/)?

It's centered in Chrome, FF, and Safari. Heck, it'd probably work on an Etch-a-Sketch if I could load the code on it...but not IE8.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on an etch-a-sketch `:P`

Comment: @Sime. Doesn't work on mine. What version do you have? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Android :) (I'm kidding)

Comment: You should consider [edit]ing your question to include the appropriate code. We expect all questions to be self-contained, without requiring people to access external resources. Consider what happens when your page goes down, or you change the design. Your question (and all of the answers!) would become useless. Also, by posting the relevant code inline, you make it much easier for people to see and help you with your problem. No one wants to dig through *all of your CSS*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly set your FOOTER element to a block for IE8.

```
#colophon {
    display: block;
}
```

---

Btw, consider including this to your page: http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="path/to/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

It fixed these kinds of things.

Comment: You have to set all the new HTML5 elements for IE8 and lower (possibly 9 as well, not 100% certain) as it doesn't understand them and doesn't know if they should be inline or block elements.